# Null checks for beans that have not been created due to Profile

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I have an unusual problem that requires a redesign and decoupling exercise.  This however is a short-term fix until the time comes for the redesign

So I have created a number of Spring profiles on a number of configuration classes that, unless active, will stop the creation of a number of beans.  There are some classes that will still try to use the beans should they be active, but obviously, if the profiles remain inactive they will not be created, and so I will need to handle some null pointers.

Is there a more elegant way to check these other that:

```
if (Objects.isNull(objectBean)) {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Not supported at this time");
}
```

Also, with this approach, Sonar complains at the use of checked exceptions.

Comment: How are you injecting those beans then?  `@AutoWired(required = false)` ?

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly how I'm injecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UnsupportedOperationException`, which is a standard Java exception that is not checked.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this one.  Sorted the Sonar issue out.